# Is there any way in Xcode to improve the audio playback quality?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, sample-rate

I'm making a app that gives users a rich collection of natural sounds.
However the tracks are in 48khz and I need to reduce them to 38khz so that the size of the app could go down.I'll be using AVFoundation to play the audio.
Now I'm worrying that this will lead to reduction in sound quality.
Is there any way in Xcode to improve audio quality during playback.

Comment: Refer and try https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/index.html .

Comment: Thank you.
I'll certainly look into it.

Comment: What format is your original source material in?  Sample rate conversions tend not to improve audio quality.

Comment: The original format is .wav

Answer (score 1):

If you use a compressed format you are looking at a 10 times file size reduction from using WAV which is not compressed ... this way you could keep your sample rate of 48 kHz ... if you must use WAV then also look at reducing bit depth ... two fundamental factors determine audio quality :  sample rate & bit depth ... CD quality audio uses 44.1 kHz sample rate with a bit depth of 16 bits

On iOS look at compression using AAC ... for a more broadly accepted non patent encumbered compression check out FLAC

Three nice command line tools to perform all manor of audio format conversion :   avconv, ffmpeg and sox

Comment: Thank you for answering,but the real issue with me hear is that is there any I can let Xcode know to take advantage of this HQ tracks and provide better playback?Once again thanks.